# Quartiles and mean by multiple groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have to do a calculation of quartiles, but I need to group the data by two different conditions. First of all I need to group them by which position they hold in the company, but then I also need to group them by which union they are a part of.  Here is an example of my data:

```
Position    Union   Salary
Consultant  A   1000
Receptionist    B   700
Consultant  A   1250
Consultant  A   1200
HR  A   1100
HR  B   800
Receptionist    B   750
Student B   200
HR  B   700
Consultant  A   900
Student B   300
HR  A   1500
Consultant  A   1300
Consultant  B   800
Consultant  A   1300
Receptionist    B   780
Student B   250
Consultant  B   950
HR  A   1150
Consultant  A   1275
```

I've tried a number of different ways to go about this, including some very early tests with ddply, but I've also tried out summarise for instance:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(Union, Position) %>%
  summarise(Salary= quantile(Salary))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: several users helped me out with a great solution in the comments, thank you very much. I have an additional question though:

I also need to calculate the mean of the salaries by the same conditions.

I tried using the code akrun provided (which worked very well on the quartiles), but when I did this for the mean (`x <- x %>% group_by(Union, Position) %>% do(data.frame(., as.list(mean(.$Salary))))`) it delivered a variable for each group, instead of merging into one variable and adding it at the end.

Can anyone tell me some way to fix this?

Comment: The only issue with that `summarise` solution is that you can do one quartile at a time. You could try `do`.

Comment: Where is the `loen` column?  If it is `Salary`, then try `x %>% group_by(Union, Position) %>% do(data.frame(., as.list(quantile(.$Salary))))`

Comment: dplyr's `summarise` expects a single value per group as return. Hence, you can do it using a list-column, like `x <- df %>% group_by(Position, Union) %>% summarise(q = list(quantile(Salary)))` and then either `x$q` or `library(tidyr); unnest(x)`

Comment: @akrun: could you please remove the [duplicate]. I don't see how you can answer this question from the question you've linked to.

Comment: @Nordsted  What is the expected output?  The comments already showed couple of ways and the duplicate also shows the same.  Also, in your edit, you are using `mean` which is different than your original question about `quantile`  For `mean` you can use `x %>% group_by(Union, Position) %>% summarise(Salary = mean(Salary))`

Comment: @akrun They sure did, but I figured that instead of asking a new question, I would simply expand this question (it does still revolve around the group_by command and is within dplyr). Not sure if that was the right move though, I'm a little new to Stack Overflow as a user. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: @Nordsted  I can reopen this post.  But somebody else would dupe tag it later based on the similarity of the post.  Also, there are lots of dupes for group by mean.  So, I am not sure if reopening makes sense or not

Comment: @akrun Don't bother, I think I just need to learn how to better search for answers. Thank you very much for your assistance